# Exception starting keycloak on docker with mssql

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have a MSSQL Database on a server. This database already has the schema created, sucessfully, by the docker image. However, when running this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=mssql -e DB_USER=myuser -e DB_PASSWORD=mypassword -e DB_ADDR=myaddress -e DB_DATABASE=Keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:11.0.0
```

It gives me the following exception, and it stops the docker from running any further:

```
08:41:33,715 INFO [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown 
08:41:33,721 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] 
08:41:33,751 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2 
08:41:33,755 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped users cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,753 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorization cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,767 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realms cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,770 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped keys cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,786 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,780 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending 
08:41:33,791 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineSessions cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,790 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,794 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped loginFailures cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,793 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped work cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,800 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped actionTokens cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,800 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped clientSessions cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,801 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080 
08:41:33,806 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container 
08:41:33,808 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container 
08:41:33,808 INFO [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopping cache manager null on 2c527d1cdbfe 
08:41:33,813 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.1.3.Final stopping 
08:41:33,819 INFO [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopping cache manager null on 2c527d1cdbfe 
08:41:33,829 INFO [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb 
08:41:33,832 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 455ms 
08:41:33,838 INFO [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb 
08:41:33,876 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:86)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have no idea what I should do, I already tried adding the `JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false` but it didn't work.

Comment: did you get this solved? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, by scrolling up in the logs I realised there was an SQL error before this block. For me it was 2 groups with the same name but different cases
Ex :
Group_A
Group_a

Deleting one fixed the issue but it could be a different error in your case.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Thank you for answering this post. You are answering a very old question. Is your answer directly answering the question? A good answer (even if its your own experience) will contain a reproducible example of what you faced.

Comment: Yes, my anwser is for the exact same situation as the original post and it seems we aren't the only ones who had this issue.  I don't have the log trace anymore because the old container was deleted but it was pretty much indentical to OP. To be more precise about the problem : When you migrate Keycloak, it gracefully stops on error. It is a bit misleading because the last error shown isn't the one causing the problem. If you scroll up you'll see the exact reason why it stops. In my case it was an SQL error for duplicates, but in anyone else's case the SQL error might be for a different reason

Comment: that's good, you can add these details to your answer if you want to and score an upvote!